# Swift firebase .observe or .observeSingleEvent won't work

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a problem with my firebase .observe and .observeSingleEvent.

```
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let postRef = ref.child("posts").child("post")
    print(postRef)

    postRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        if let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            print(postDict)
        }
    }
```

I do this in my viewDidLoad().
the 'print(postRef)' prints the right path to my firebase.

```
https://-----.firebaseio.com/posts/post
```

After that I get nothing returned.

child structure:
[child structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXNdM.png)

Why won't it print the "postDict"?

Now I see this in my project:
[CFNetwork/Foundation/Security.framework turns red!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McUCX.png)

Comment: Post your child structure, you're probably looking on the wrong child.

Comment: Also, try printing the snapshot before the cast, maybe you're getting nil on the cast

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht I Already tried that. Nothing print to the console..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I re-added the missing frameworks ->

```
project -> build phases -> Link Binary Libraries
```

It worked again!
Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 0):

Check your database rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out following solutions:

1. Delete GoogleService-Info.plist from project and redownload it from
       firebase and add it to your project, i think its connection problem
       otherwise it would print something in the console.
2. Also tell me is something printing in console which says 'you dont
   have read permissions' ? if yes you need to reset your firebase db
   rules to default otherwise solution no 1 should work.

Comment: Just tried that! Stil nothing.. Now is see that I have an other problem. Check original post for what I mean. thanks!